# UTL_FILE output file is missing

Tags: oracle

Try to output some results into windows folder "c:\temp". Compile and run my procedure without any issue, but I cannot find my output file "c:\temp\foo.log". Here is my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE  DIRECTORY tmp AS 'c:\temp\';


    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE write_log
    AS
       CURSOR cur
       IS
          SELECT firstname,
                 lastname
          FROM   MEMBER
          WHERE  memberid BETWEEN 2 AND 5; -- only test 3 rows.

       fname MEMBER.firstname%TYPE;
       lname MEMBER.lastname%TYPE;
       outputrecord VARCHAR2 ( 255 );
       outputfile UTL_FILE.file_type;
    BEGIN
       OPEN cur;

       FETCH cur
       INTO  fname,
             lname;

       outputfile := UTL_FILE.fopen ( UPPER ( 'tmp' ),
                                      'foo.log',
                                      'W',
                                      32767
                                    );

       WHILE cur%FOUND
       LOOP
          outputrecord := fname || ',' || lname;
          UTL_FILE.put ( outputfile, outputrecord );
          UTL_FILE.new_line ( outputfile );

          FETCH cur
          INTO  fname,
                lname;
       END LOOP;

       CLOSE cur;

       UTL_FILE.fclose ( outputfile );
    END write_log;
    /

    BEGIN
       write_log;
    END;
    /
```

Did I do something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at `c:\temp` on the database server?  Or on your client machine?  `UTL_FILE` runs on the database server so it can only read and write files on the database server not on your client machine.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I found the file located at server side c:\temp folder. I was looking for the file from client machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UTL_FILE` manipulates files on the database server, not on your client machine.  You can only read and write files on the database server.  Assuming that this code runs successfully, it would create a file on the database server named `c:\temp\foo.log`.